# Setting some Rows and Entries in a Matrix to 0

Tags: matrix, code-request, infinite-loop

How can I set certain entries in a matrix to be 0?

Given an $m\times n$ matrix with specified values:

```
mat = Table[1/i, {i, n}, {j, m}]
```

I want to make some entries 0: I will replace row $i$ with zeros when the greatest prime factor of $i$ exceeds the greatest prime factor of $n$:

```
GreatestPrimeFactor[1] := 1
GreatestPrimeFactor[n_Integer?Positive] := FactorInteger[n][[-1, 1]]
ReplacePart[m, {i_,j_}/; GreatestPrimeFactor[i]>GreatestPrimeFactor[n]-
>0]
```

I also want to set additional entries to 0, but before I do that, I want to record something to recall later; e.g., the column sums.

```
Total[mat, {1}]
```

Then I also set the $(i,j)$ entry to be $0$ when $j/\gcd(i,j)$ is composite:

```
 ReplacePart[m, {i_,j_}/;compositeQ[j/GCD[i,j]]->0]
```

How can this be done in the table environment? I will consider using `Array` instead of `Table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
condition[i_, j_, n_] := FactorInteger[i][[-1, 1]] <= FactorInteger[n][[-1, 1]] && 
   (j/GCD[i, j] == 1 || PrimeQ[j/GCD[i, j]])
```

**Using SparseArray:**

```
sa[m_, n_] := SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; condition[i, j, n] -> 1/i}, {m, n}]
```

Example:

```
sa[10, 10] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &
>    \frac{1}{2} \\
>  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}
>    & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
>  \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} \\
>  \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 &
>    \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8}
>    & 0 & \frac{1}{8} \\
>  \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 & \frac{1}{9} & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & 0
>    & \frac{1}{10} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Using Table:**

```
table[m_, n_] := Table[If[condition[i, j, n], 1/i, 0], {i, n}, {j, m}]

Normal[sa[10, 10]] == table[10, 10]
```

> True

Comment: @TheSubstitute, i think it is fixed now (replacing `||` with `&&` in `condition`)

Comment: Thanks. Why are there zeros in column 1? Can we avoid calling 1 a composite in the code?

Comment: @TheSubstitute, changed `condition` to fix that issue.